# changing the backcolor of a panel changes the backcolor for all panels

Tags: winforms, custom-controls

I have a custom control, OrderEntryCtl, with a TableLayoutPanel that uses Panels insided of the cells of the first row (call it the header row, the Panels are named HeaderPanel1, HeaderPanel2, etc[8 panels altogether, 1 for each column in row 0 of the TableLayoutPanel]). The BackColor of each Panel is set to blue first. At some point, I want to change the BackColor of each Panel to gray. Here's the problem I am running into: Changing the BackColor of 1 panel actually changes the BackColor of all Panels on all of my OrderEntryCtl's added to the Form.
FYI: I'm not creating any of the panels dynamically; they are all created via the designer and the code created by VS is in OrderEntryCtl.Designer.cs

So, consider, I have some number of OrderEntryCtl's on my form (these are added programmatically/dynamically at run time by my code, not by the designer). A user interacts with the first OrderEntryCtl (call it OrderEntry1), then clicks a button that's a part of the control. The click event handler for that button needs to turn the 8 HeaderPanel's to gray:

```
HeaderPanel1.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
HeaderPanel2.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
HeaderPanel3.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
//etc
```

I'm expecting only the 8 header Panels to turn gray for OrderEntry1, however, ALL header Panels for ALL OrderEntryCtl's are turning gray. The really odd thing is, I could comment out the last 7 "HeaderPanel#.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;" commands, leaving only HeaderPanel1.BackColor = Color.DarkGray; and this still happens. But, if I add to the event handler

```
HeaderPanel2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
```

only the border style of panel 2 of OrderEntry1 is affected, which is the expected behavior!
How do I get the BackColor property to behave the same as the BorderStyle property for my panels?

In response to first comment, I've included the code in the Designer.cs

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel HeaderPanel1;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel HeaderPanel2;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel HeaderPanel3;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel HeaderPanel4;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel HeaderPanel5;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel HeaderPanel6;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel HeaderPanel7;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel HeaderPanel8;
this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
this.HeaderPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
this.HeaderPanel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
this.HeaderPanel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
this.HeaderPanel4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
this.HeaderPanel5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
this.HeaderPanel6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
this.HeaderPanel7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
this.HeaderPanel8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
this.HeaderPanel1.SuspendLayout();
this.HeaderPanel2.SuspendLayout();
this.HeaderPanel3.SuspendLayout();
this.HeaderPanel4.SuspendLayout();
this.HeaderPanel5.SuspendLayout();
this.HeaderPanel6.SuspendLayout();
this.HeaderPanel7.SuspendLayout();
this.HeaderPanel8.SuspendLayout();
// 
// tableLayoutPanel1
// 
this.tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 8;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 24F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 16F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 26F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 24F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 15F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 15F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 12F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 18F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.HeaderPanel1, 0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.HeaderPanel2, 1, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.HeaderPanel3, 2, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.HeaderPanel4, 3, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.HeaderPanel5, 4, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.HeaderPanel6, 5, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.HeaderPanel7, 6, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.HeaderPanel8, 7, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(944, 90);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
// 
// HeaderPanel1
// 
this.HeaderPanel1.BackColor = global::WdRx.Fulfillment.Dispensing.Workstation.Properties.Settings.Default.OrderEntryHeader;
this.HeaderPanel1.Controls.Add(this.Lbl_Header1);
this.HeaderPanel1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("BackColor", global::WdRx.Fulfillment.Dispensing.Workstation.Properties.Settings.Default, "OrderEntryHeader", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
this.HeaderPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.HeaderPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(675, 0);
this.HeaderPanel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.HeaderPanel1.Name = "HeaderPanel1";
this.HeaderPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 45);
this.HeaderPanel1.TabIndex = 10;
```

Ok, after reviewing the above, I realize my problem is that I am associating the BackColor property to a color defined in my config file, and I'm doing this for all of the panels. The binding is for the property changed event, so change the property on 1 panel, updates all panels.

So, I'm now taking suggestions on how to still fetch my initial color from my config file, but without binding the OnPropertyChange event ? ? ? Anyone ?

Comment: "The really odd thing is, I could comment out the last 7 "HeaderPanel#.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;" commands, leaving only HeaderPanel1.BackColor = Color.DarkGray; and this still happens."  Sounds like all your other panels are actually **contained** within the first one.  You sure you didn't accidentally "nest" them when placing them on the form?

Comment: Just don't use (DataBindings), use (ApplicationSettings) in the Property window.